# Is storing an array of objects in ASP.NET viewstate the best solution for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wondering if storing the data in viewstate is a good idea for this given problem.
He's a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve, firstly we have a Repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox id="Name" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="Age" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:TextBox id="NewPersonName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="NewPersonAge" runat="server" />
<asp:Buttin id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick"Button1_Click"/>
```

To keep things simple I'll forego the databinding code, as this is working it loads in the current list of people and ages and binds perfectly.

The problem is with the bottom 3 controls, what I want is for the user to be able to type in a new entry, click the add button and this would then be added to the Repeater, but not persisted to the database.

The user should be able to add multiple names to the list and then click a Save button to commit all the new names in one click rather than committing for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

Are you persisting the entire list from the database in the viewstate or just the uncommitted additions?

If it's just the additions, then this is a fine use of viewstate.

If the list from the DB isn't very large or volatile, then I guess that'd be OK, too.

Comment: It is the database list and the uncommitted additions, both of which are not expected to be large lists on a single web page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a DataTable object and store it in the user's session. That way you have a quick way of data binding the upon each add/modify/delete and you can simple clear it out of the session when the processing is done. In addition, you could easily access the user list on a separate page if it was deemed necessary.

EDIT: One other caveat is that if necessary, you can easily drop a DataView on top of this is you need to do some quick sorting/filtering of the user list.

Comment: This is what I would do (maybe would consider rolling my own classes and serializing a list of these).
As session data stays around after you leave the page it would be generally a good idea ensure the session is clear on the first request:
if (!IsPostBack)
 Session['Users'] = new DataTable();

Comment: Good idea, but the only show stopper is with the session object could expire causing the user to lose their current work as the entries might be entered over a day, but thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: Another drawback to sessions is that they are stored on the server. Viewstate is stored in the page itself.

Comment: I'd be cautious about letting a web page stay "open" for that long of a time period. A lot of things can happen on both the front end and on the back end that would render the ViewState a problem as well.

Comment: I'd be wary of using Session as well. You're dealing with client-side data. The only advantage of using Session would be that it persists when you go to another page, which is kind of pointless if you are clearing the session anyway if !PostBack. Session isn't really meant for this. Viewstate is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use javascript and store it in object arrays.  Then, the client side would reference the javascript arrays for building the UI.

You might take a look at some of the javascript frameworks like yahoo yui, script.aculo.us, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle this in one of two ways. The first would be JS arrays and do clientside adding to the repeater/viewing mechanism.

The other option would be to have a table in my DB where I store these uncommitted additions, and then just query them back out.

and in truth I'd probably do a combination of the two. Use AJAX to send the data to the uncommitted list table asynchronously while I'm building the new nodes for my display.

On the SAVE/COMMIT button, I'd send the commit command to the server asynchronously which moves the user's items from the uncommitted tableto the committed table.